# T is invertible if and only if $||(T_{n})^{-1}|| \leq M$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space.  Let $(T_{n})$ be a sequence of invertible operators in $B(X)$ and let $T \in B(X)$ be the uniform limit of $(T_{n})$, i.e., $||T_{n}-T||\rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Show that

T is invertible if and only if $||(T_{n})^{-1}|| \leq M$ for some M,

in which case $||(T_{n})^{-1}-T^{-1}|| \rightarrow 0$.

This is the question I'm working on at the moment.

For the left to right direction $T$ and $T_{n}$ are invertible and hence injective and surjective with $T_{n}^{-1}:X \rightarrow X$ and $T^{-1}:X \rightarrow X$, or, as $T, T_{n} \in B(X)$ we can say ran$(T_{n})$ is dense in $X$ and $||T_{n}x|| \leq c||x||$ and similar for $T$ but I'm not sure how this allows me to proceed.

Comment: what is $B(X)$?

Comment: Sorry, it's the set of bounded linear operators from X to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the following facts :

**Claim 1.** The set $G$ of invertible operators is open.

**Claim 2.** $T\to T^{-1}$ is continuous on $G$.

If $T, T_n \in G$ then by continuity of $T\to T^{-1}$ we have $T_n^{-1}\to T^{-1}$ so $(T_n^{-1})$ is bounded.

If $\|(T_{n})^{-1}\| \leq M$ then $\|T_n^{-1}T-Id\|=\|T_n^{-1}(T-T_n)\|\leq M\|T-T_n\|\to 0$. For a sufficiently large $n$ it means that $X=T_n^{-1}T$ is invertible (since $G$ is open there is a open neighbourhood $V$ of $I_d$ such that $V\subset G$). Then $T=T_nX$ is invertible.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  Do you mind if I ask what you mean by $T \rightarrow T^{-1}$?

Comment: The map which associate to any operator in $G$ its inverse.